# Best way to parse lat and lon string

Tags: python, string, split, numbers, python-re

I want to convert one string, which contains lat and lon values, to two floats. However, the string may be separated by mixing commas and spaces, such as `28.111,77.222`, `28.111, 77.222`, `28.111 77.222`, `28.111   77.222`.

I have tried this method:

```
import re

test = '28.111,77.222'
res = re.findall(r'\d+', test)
lat = res[0]
lon = res[1]
```

It only works for int, how about float numbers like this case?

Comment: _"how about float numbers"_ - `\d+\.\d+`? See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/4736/3001761.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, it's the better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

examples = "28.111,77.222", "28.111, 77.222", "28.111 77.222", "28.111   77.222"

# split on spaces and/or commas
[re.split(",| ", example) for example in examples]
# [['28.111', '77.222'], ['28.111', '', '77.222'], ['28.111', '77.222'], ['28.111', '', '', '77.222']]
```